# What is the process of obtaining a commercial license after revocation?

Tags: faa-regulations, faa

I held a 2nd class medical and a commercial pilot license. My certificates were revoked due to an alleged DUI which I didn't get convicted of. I have been trying to contact every division in the FAA just to speak with someone about the process of getting my certificates back, however, due to COVID-19 not a soul is in the office nor, apparently, returning phone calls. Any ideas on which direction to go to obtain my certificates? Or possibly a direct number to someone to speak with about the matter?

Comment: Have they actually revoked the certs, or just threatened action? There should have been several letters, with details on what information they wanted, when to respond, your rights, etc. Also, are you sure it is both certs? A DWI is normally only disqualifying for the medical cert, not the pilot cert.

Answer (score 6):

If your pilot's certificate was definitely revoked then it's gone for good. You'll have to reapply and re-qualify for all your certificates and ratings again, although you have to wait a year first per [14 CFR 61.13(d)(2)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&n=14y2.0.1.1.2&r=PART#se14.2.61_113):

> Unless otherwise authorized by the Administrator, a person whose
> pilot, flight instructor, or ground instructor certificate has been
> revoked may not apply for any certificate, rating, or authorization
> for 1 year after the date of revocation.

Certificate revocation [is the FAA's 'nuclear option'](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2017/may/flight-training-magazine/career-pilot-revoked) and they don't do it lightly. Your best option here is to contact AOPA (if you're a member) and/or an aviation lawyer for specific advice.